# local variable 'post' referenced before assignment - flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to create a post request with Flask and I keep getting this error: local variable 'post' referenced before assignment. I have seen many Stack questions like this but I can't seem to find the right answer for this. This may be an easy mistake, but I'm new to Flask. Thanks.

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for
from flask import redirect, jsonify
from db.db import BlogPost
from db import db

application = Flask(__name__)

db.init()

@application.route('/')
def apiRedirect():
    return redirect('/blogs')

@application.route('/blogs')
def getBlogs():
    blogs = BlogPost.objects()

    blogsarr = []
    for blog in blogs:
        blogsarr.append(blog.to_mongo())    

    return jsonify(blogsarr)

@application.route('/blogs/create', methods=['GET','POST'])
def createBlog():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        author = request.form['author']
        date = request.form['date']
        content = request.form['content']

        post = BlogPost(author=author, date=date,content=content)
        post.save()
        return "Posted"

    return jsonify(post.author, post.date, post.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `createBlog` method, `post` object gets created only when `request.method == 'POST'`. But when the method is `GET` it wont be created. So you would hit the error `local variable 'post' referenced before assignment`

Comment: And when he does create the `post` object, he doesn't return it, because he does `return "Posted"` instead.